# Ref<?> modify a field from object and save it when saving containing object

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am using Objectify for Google Cloud Datastore.

I am looking into `Ref<?>` and tried to see if I can modify a property from the object with this annotation but it doesn't seem to be saved in my datastore.

Example:

I have these classes, I'll exlude setters and getters.

```
@Entity
class Car {
    @Id Long id;
    @Load Ref<Person> driver;    // Person is an @Entity
}

class Person {
   @Id Long id;
   String name;
}
```

If I do this

```
Car car = new Car();
car.driver = Ref.create(driverKey);
ofy().save().entity(car).now();

Car fetched = ofy().load().entity(car).now();
fetched.driver.get().setName("Pepito");
ofy().save().entity(car).now();
```

It won't change the name of the `Person` in the database.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References are just that - references to separate entities with separate lives. There is no cascading save. If you want to save the driver, do it explicitly.